# biztalk administration console crash when browsing for folder

Tags: biztalk

We recently upgraded our biztalk server 2006R2 to SP1. The problem is that we're having some small issues now, for example the administration console crashes when I browse for a folder if I want to make a file send/receive port.

Any idea what might cause this problem?

I'm having no problems when I browse for a folder with our normal explorer and then copy paste its address into the biztalk folder browser.

Comment: Try re-installing.  2006 and 2006 R2 are full of these little quirks.

Comment: What Cumulative Update is your BizTalk 2006R2 up to?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update towards the latest CU for your service pack.

For BizTalk 2006 R2 with SP1, this is CU4.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2682056 for more information on CU4 for BizTalk 2006 SP1.

If this still does not help, there is a temporary workaround to export/import bindings of existing receive locations/send ports with a FILE adapter. This allows you to still create the ports/locations you need and unblocks the situation.

In any case, if the problem persists, you might want to check with Microsoft about the issue.

That is in case your license includes the extended support option which lasts until 12 July 2016.
If you don't have extended support, the support ended on July 11th 2011 I'm afraid...